# Переходы в windows forms внутри одного окна

Tags: c#, winforms

Практикуясь в программировании графического приложения в forms, столкнулся с необходимостью плавного перехода между формами. Т.е. необходимо, чтобы содержимое формы обновлялось практически полностью, при этом не возникало нового окна (хотелось бы, чтобы вся программа выполнялась в одном окне).
Пробовал создать панели из элементов, и при необходимости одну помещать поверх другой. Но при таком подходе достаточно неудобно редактировать интерфейс, особенно, если панелей много.
Существуют способы реализовать эту задумку?

Answer (score 2):

Для проектирования UI каждой панели используйте отдельные файлы на базе UserControl. Он полностью поддерживает все design-time фичи. А затем используйте получившиеся компоненты вместо панелей.

Comment: Дополню, чтобы не разводить лапшу из кода - нужен какой-то класс-контроллер, которому будут централизованно отправляться команды и который будет держать список состояний, а так-же создавать и иметь ссылки на данные панели и был доступ к управлению текущим окном формы - какое окно активно, итд... Чтобы не было такого, что в основном классе формы происходит жонглирование панелями.